# In the following case, which one is better ? fread() or mmap()?

Tags: c, linux, memory, mmap, fread

I want to read two files via a process, the first file is about 2G, the second file is about 20M. 
They look like this:

```
1   1217907
1   1217908
1   1517737
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

Now I plan to read the whole file into memory, then use `strtok_r()` to get the value of each num and store them in a data structure array. 4 processes may read these two files on the same computer at almost same time. The computer is 64-bit, physical memory maybe 4G or even less. My question is, which method is more efficient ? `fread()` or `mmap()` ?

Here is the key part of my program of reading the whole file(since someone wants to see it,but I don't know whether it is related to my question):

```
typedef struct My_Edge
{
int first;
int second;
}Edge;

Edge *myEdge;

int Read_Whole_File()
{

fseek(wholeFile, 0, SEEK_END);

long int fileSize=ftell(wholeFile);

char *buffer=malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize+1);

fseek(wholeFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, wholeFile);

char *string_first;
char *string_second;
char *save_ptr;

int temp_first;
int temp_second;

string_first = strtok_r(buffer, " \t\n", &save_ptr);
int i=0;

int temp_edge_num;
Edge *temp_edge;

while (string_first != NULL)
{
    temp_first = atoi(string_first);

    string_second = strtok_r(NULL," \t\n",&save_ptr);

    temp_second = atoi(string_second);

    if(i>=my_edge_num)
    {
        temp_edge_num = i + EDGE_NUM_ADJUST;

        temp_edge = realloc(myEdge, sizeof(Edge)*temp_edge_num);
        if(temp_edge)
        {
            myEdge = temp_edge;
        }
        my_edge_num = temp_edge_num;

    }

    if((p_id[temp_first]==*partitionID)||(p_id[temp_second]==*partitionID))
    {
        myEdge[i].first=temp_first;
        myEdge[i].second=temp_second;
        i++;
    }

    string_first = strtok_r(NULL, " \t\n", &save_ptr);

}

return 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to use `mmap()`, but it has EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I use `strtok_r()` tp process the var which is processed by `mmap()`:

char *buffer;

```
struct stat fileStat;

fstat(wholeFile, &fileStat);

buffer = mmap(NULL, fileStat.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, wholeFile, 0);

char *string_first;
char *string_second;
char *save_ptr;

int temp_first;
int temp_second;

string_first = strtok_r(buffer, " \t\n", &save_ptr);//EXC_BAD_ACCESS here, the content of buffer is correct.
```

Comment: Why don't you use some database instead of 2G file?

Comment: It is our assignment, our professor doesn't allow us to use database.

Comment: Why do you need to read the whole file in to memory in order to process its contents serially (that is, line by line in order)?

Comment: I think to read the whole file into memory then process it is much faster than read it from file line by line .

Comment: Not necessarily. The OS will in any case read it in blocks and if there is no random access to it the speed difference is minimal. If the assignment is not about finding an optimal way to read a file, I'd consider this as premature optimization.

Comment: Try both `fread` and `mmap` and apply your algorithm and actual test scenario and profile it.

Comment: The assignment has requirement for the time of reading the file. So I have to find the fastest way to read the file and store the data. I tried use fscanf() or frets() or fgetc(), I find that the approach of fread() it at first and then use strtok_r() to get each data is the fastest. But I don't know whether mmap() is faster.

Comment: `mmap` should be faster than `fread` in this case. You will not know for sure, if you don't try. Show us both your solutions - maybe there are other ways to make them faster.

Comment: Pretty sure the one that actually works is the fastest.

Comment: If the goal is to minimize the time to process (as opposed to just read) the file, notice that the processing doesn't even start until the whole file is read in.  What if you could process one part of the file while the next part is being read in?

Comment: @ScottHunter You mean using multithread ? One thread to read and another thread to process ?

Comment: @ScottHunter If using multithread to read them and process them, it only reduces very little time because of the overhead, I already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, which method is more efficient ? fread() or mmap() ?

First of all, let's look how fread and mmap works on linux:
`fread`:
Let's say we work with ext4 file system (without encryption),
fread use some internal buffer and if no data in it,
it calls `read`, `read` execute "system call"
and after some time we jump to:
fs/read_write.c::vfs_read
and after more work we reach
mm/filemap.c::generic_file_read_iter

And in this function we fill inode page cache and read to this
page cache data.

So we do the basically the same as "mmap" does.

The difference that that in `fread` case we not directly
works with pages, we just copy portion of data from kernel
inode page cache to user space buffer,
in `mmap` we have page cache directly in program
memory space. Plus in `fread` when no page in "inode page cache"
we just read it, but in `mmap` that cause "page fault",
and only after that we read it.

Both variants use "read pages ahead" strategy.
The possible difference may be in "cache" policy,
we can control it in "mmap" case with `madvise` and flags of `mmap`.

So I suppose the answer is "they are almost the same in terms of speed in sequence read case like yours".